# Magento 2 widget with js

Tags: magento2, javascript, widgets

Tell me please how to create my own Magento 2 widget with custom JS. I need something like a "scroll to top" button, but with another function. I'm allready have a worked script, but how i can create a widget with them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have created **"Custom Widget"** **Module** as per your requirement.

app/code/Widget/CustomWidget/registration.php

**Registration.php**

```
<?php

use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Widget_CustomWidget', __DIR__);
```

app/code/Widget/CustomWidget/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Widget_CustomWidget" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

app/code/Widget/CustomWidget/etc/widget.xml

**Widget.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
    <widget id="widget_customwidget" class="Widget\CustomWidget\Block\Widget\ContactInformations">
        <label translate="true">Custom Widget For Scroll to Top</label>
        <description>Custom Widget</description>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

app/code/Widget/CustomWidget/Block/Widget/ContactInformations.php

**ContactInformations.php**

```
<?php
namespace Widget\CustomWidget\Block\Widget; 
class ContactInformations extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template implements \Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface
{
     protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('widget/contact_informations.phtml');
    }
}
```

app/code/Widget/CustomWidget/view/frontend/templates/widget/contact_informations.phtml

**contact_informations.phtml**

```
Link: <a href="#switcher-language" class="toTop">Scroll to TOP &uarr;</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
     require(['jquery','smoothscroll'],function($){
     });
</script>
```

app/code/Widget/CustomWidget/view/frontend/web/js/smoothscroll.js

**smoothscroll.js**

```
jQuery('.toTop ').click(function(){
        //alert("hello world");
      jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
      return false;
   });
   jQuery('.toBottom').click(function(){
      jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 600);
      return false;
});
```

app/code/Widget/CustomWidget/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "smoothscroll": "Widget_CustomWidget/js/smoothscroll"
        }
    }
};
```

After creating above module first run **setup:upgrade** command

Call your widget on the page where you want Scroll To Top link ,  by adding following line.(I have called this on homepage and its working fine ).

```
{{widget type="Widget\CustomWidget\Block\Widget\ContactInformations"}}
```

After above all steps run below commands :

1. Run **setup:static-content:deploy**(as we are creating customjs)
2. Run **cache:clean** command

Comment: I'am not sure  but i just wonder if the

Comment: I accidentally hit  ENTER, and the editing expired after 5 minutes, what the ..... I just wonder if the requirejs([],[]) here would work. because the "map" keyword doesnt make the regular scroll.js code automatically an AMD module that requirejs depneds on. Pls correct if i am wrong.

Comment: @robertshare  i have used require js here to only load over smoothscroll.js , as i have created smoothscroll as a seprate so if any change needed they can directly customize and change there so here use of requirejs is correct i am just loading my smoothscroll.js via require js . Hope it clears to you

Comment: I checked the requirejs docs again, you are right.